# 80s/90s obscure movie taking place in boy's bedroom

Tags: identify-this-movie

My daycare provider played this movie for us and can't find anything about it online. What I remember:

- opening credits are animated but the movie is not. However the set is meant to appear hand-drawn (his bed, his dresser, etc) even though everything is 3 dimensional
- entire movie takes place in his bedroom
- he is stuck in his room for some reason - I think by his mom until he cleans it
- something goes wonky with his radio when he listens to music and it "talks" to him
- at one point his room becomes a jungle with vines and monkey puppets and snakes and he is dressed like Tarzan. He sings a song with the monkeys but I don't remember if the puppets sing
- at one point, two giant puppet legs and feet drop from the ceiling and attempt to stomp on him or something. He jumps and kicks them to make them go away but they don't
- there might be a monster or something in his closet?
- eventually everything returns to normal but can't remember why or how

I was born in '83 and went to daycare until mid 90s so would guess this movie was made in late 80s but not sure. Think it was American made - don't remember accents. This was not a scary movie and fairly certain meant for kids.

Comment: A very detailed question (and well-remembered). +1 and answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you're after [In Search of the Wow Wow Wibble Woggle Wazzie Woodle Woo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0312805/combined) *[actual title!!]* from 1985 about a boy (played by a man) stuck in his white room to do his homework and imagining many fantastic worlds. At one point the whole room turns into a jungle and the boy is dressed like Tarzan and sings with a monkey doll; at another, giant legs appear and he sings a song about them. He's also afraid of the monster in the closet and the set is exactly as you remembered it. Here's a clip from the film, where he hears the radio and it suddenly starts talking to him about the closet: